# How to add Oracle database connection to AnalyzeforMSD script?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, msd

I use this script right now:

```
import os, arcpy

directory = r"C:\Project"
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
  for myFile in files:
    fileExt = os.path.splitext(myFile)[1]
    if (fileExt == ".mxd"):
        fullPath = os.path.join(root, myFile)
        print myFile

        myMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
        analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(myMap)

for key in ('messages', 'warnings', 'errors'):
print "----" + key.upper() + "---"
vars = analysis[key]
for ((message, code), layerlist) in vars.iteritems():
print "    ", message, " (CODE %i)" % code
print "       applies to:",
for layer in layerlist:
print layer.name,
print
```

It runs on many project mxds. And every time it analyzes a mxd file I`m asked the connection dialogue and have to enter the connection details.

Is there a way to open a database connection that is valid for all mxd?

Comment: Just a guess - try the Create ArcSDE Connection file tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000pt000000   I do know when you run the tool it validates by making a connection to SDE. So, I'm thinking by using this it might persist the open connection in your script, thus allowing you to analyze.

Comment: Didn`t work for me

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to stand by my answer I posted as a comment.
In the following script:

```
import arcpy

myMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'c:\temp\sde.mxd')
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(myMap)
print analysis
```

I get this:

> {'errors': {(u"Layer's data source is inaccessible", 3): [, ]},
>   'messages': {}, 'warnings': {}}

(with the dialog box as you explain)

However, in this script which uses CreateDataBaseConnection (or use CreateArcSDE if you're using the SDE tier to connect through):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management("c:/temp","kevin1","SQL_SERVER","ne2k864","DATABASE_AUTH","sde","sde","SAVE_USERNAME","kevin","#","TRANSACTIONAL","sde.DEFAULT","#")

myMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'c:\temp\sde.mxd')
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(myMap)
print analysis
```

I get:

> {'errors': {}, 'messages': {(u'Layer draws at all scale ranges',
>   30003): []}, 'warnings': {}}

If you have layers coming from multiple databases with multiple credentials you'll have to create a connection for each one of those. If this is a script you'll be running multiple times you'll either need to turn on overwriteOutput or delete the .SDE files prior to running again.